# How to pass value of db to auto complete text filed?

Tags: iphone

I created auto complete text box my problem is that how to pass array  is stored value which is retrive from db 
When use _category detail my app will crash .
if i'm using NSArray with objects there is no problem.
When I debug code i found problem in search method plz help to solve my problem 
Thank you so much

My function

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     self.categoryDetail = [CompanyDetailDatabase database].categoryDetail;

    NSMutableArray *arrt = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //arrt = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_categoryDetail];
    arrt=[NSArray arrayWithArray:_categoryDetail];

    self.pastUrls = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arrt];
   // self.pastUrls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Hello1",@"Hello2",@"Hello3", nil];
    self.autocompleteUrls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 180, 280, 50) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    autocompleteTableView.delegate = self;
    autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self;
    autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:autocompleteTableView];

    [txtProduct setDelegate:self];
}
- (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring {

    // Put anything that starts with this substring into the autocompleteUrls array
    // The items in this array is what will show up in the table view
    [autocompleteUrls removeAllObjects];
    for(NSString *curString in pastUrls)
    {
        NSRange substringRangeLowerCase = [curString rangeOfString:[substring lowercaseString]];
        NSRange substringRangeUpperCase = [curString rangeOfString:[substring uppercaseString]];
        if (substringRangeLowerCase.length !=0 || substringRangeUpperCase.length !=0)
        {
            [autocompleteUrls addObject:curString];
        }
    }
    autocompleteTableView.hidden =NO;
    [autocompleteTableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark UITextFieldDelegate methods

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    autocompleteTableView.hidden = NO;

    NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
    substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section {
    return autocompleteUrls.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static NSString *AutoCompleteRowIdentifier = @"AutoCompleteRowIdentifier";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [autocompleteUrls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate methods

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    txtProduct.text = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
}
```

Now view of scene image
[image: when edit textbox array value view in table view]

Comment: Post your crash report!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your methods. But, it is very simple to achieve. First you've to insert some records in your database table. And, while editing on your `UITextField` you have to pass the text to your database table as *sqlite query* with your conditions and returns as `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` Some code snippets -

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField == listTableView)
    {
        recordsArray = [self getRecords:string];

        if ([recordsArray count] == 0 || recordsArray == NULL)
        {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"No Records Were found" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
        }
        else
        {
            tableV.hidden = NO;
            [tableV reloadData];
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Above will get your typed string and pass to database method named as *getRecords* with typed string.

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getRecords:(NSString *)srchString
{
    NSMutableArray *mutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    sqlite3 *servicesDB;
    NSString *filePath=[AppDelegate dbPath];

    if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &servicesDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *sqlStatement;
        sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Records WHERE record = '%%%@%%'", srchString];
        const char *sql = [sqlStatement UTF8String];

        sqlite3_stmt *select_statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(servicesDB, sql, -1, &select_statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(select_statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
            char *record = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 0);

            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:record] forKey:@"record"];

            [mutArray addObject:[dict copy]];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error while fetching data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(servicesDB));
    }
            sqlite3_finalize(select_statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(servicesDB);
    return mutArray;
}
```

Above database method will execute and fetch the data which are all having word whatever you're typed. You can find the details about *LIKE clause* [here](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_case_sensitive_like)

You'll get your final result once the executions are completed. Simply find a [sample project here](http://d.pr/f/yKjr)